# View article update date

Tags: php, wordpress

My code is faulty and always displays the update date while the article has not been updated!

```php
<?php if (get_post_modified_time() != get_the_time()) { ?>
<li class="post-update"> بروزرسانی شده در <?php echo the_modified_time('d F Y'); ?></li>
<?php } else { ?>
<li><?php the_date('d F Y'); ?></li>
<?php } ?>
```

Please correct my codes.
thank you.

No, I did not find it.

Comment: Please don't post images of, or links to, code. Include the actual code in your post.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use same format of time in your condition. For quick resolve your issue use `get_the_modified_time()` instead of `get_post_modified_time()` as follow.

```php
<?php if (get_the_modified_time() != get_the_time()) { ?>
<li class="post-update"> بروزرسانی شده در <?php echo the_modified_time('d F Y'); ?></li>
<?php } else { ?>
<li><?php the_date('d F Y'); ?></li>
<?php } ?>
```

You can find more information on the [WordPress Developer Resources](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_modified_time/#more-information)